# NodeJS + MongoDB _message: 'book validation failed'

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I just start learning NodeJS and MongoDB. Now ı am working on a small project to learn basic stuff. But ı am getting a error, in this project ı try to insert data to mongodb which is,

userid like;
"5ed6bfe86034a81dbc7226aa" created from random numbers and letters.

But ı can not insert id to mongodb ı got an error. Here is my codes.

Firstly here is my model which is "Book.js"

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const BookSchema = new Schema({
   title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
   },

   userid: Schema.Types.ObjectId, //ı defined here no problem.

   published: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
   },
```

So, in routes folder my "book.js" like this;

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();


//Models
const Book = require('../models/Book');
const User = require('../models/Users');


/* GET book page. */
router.post('/new', function(req, res, next) {
  const book = new Book({
    title: 'Node JS',

    userid: BigInt, //ı got error here.
//what ı should write? 


    meta: {
      votes: 12,
      favs: 90
    },
    category: "History"

  });
  book.save((err, data) => {
    if (err)
      console.log(err);

    res.json(data);
  });
});
```

so when ı run my server and try to post data to mongodb with using postman ı got an error.

Like this; _message: 'book validation failed',

and more information: Error: book validation failed: userid: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "[Function: BigInt]" at path "userid"

Now, how can ı define "userid" variable? why ı got an error? what ı should write to define userid for mongodb to post data successfully? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're trying to add BigInt to userid field in book.js; BigInt is a built-in object, you instead should set `userid: 1` or `userid: BigInt(1)` according the type of that specific field, also remember that `userid` will store the user's id, so should put there a existing user id

Comment: Thanks for comment. But ı got same error. When ı try to post data to mongodb it should created automatically for userid. In Book.js ı defined but in book.js ı don't know how to define for automatic occurrence.

Comment: Try not defining userid, just don't declare that field in book.js, afaik since its automatic you don't need to set it (at least it is that way in python)

Comment: I tried. But didin't create any "userid". I think ı have to declare that field in book.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to store the _id created in user schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const BookSchema = new Schema({
   title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
   },

   userid: {
type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,
ref:User,
required:true
},
   published: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
   },
```

Then you need to fetch the user id and then store it to Book collection. By specifying ref keyword you can use populate method provided by mongoose to fetch the user info using book schema.

**Example program to fetch and save _id**

```
exports.postaddFoods=(req,res,next)=>{
  const foodname=req.body.foodname;
  const image=req.body.image;
  const shopname=req.shop.shopName;
  const price=req.body.price;
  Shop.findOne({shopName:shopname})
  .then(sid=>{
    const food= new Food({
      foodName:foodname,
      image:image,
      shopName:shopname,
      price:price,
      shopId:sid._id
    });
    return food.save()

  })
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But ı got this error;  UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of null.

I think "Schema.Types.ObjectId" returns null.

Comment: Bro i have posted the same (example) answer please check it bro.

Answer (score 0):

**This is not a solution**

@Dharani Shankar , here is my routes/book.js

```
router.post('/new', (req,res,next) => {

 Book.findOne({title: "NodeJS"})
      .then(sid => {
        const book = new Book({
            title: "Node JS",

            meta: {
            votes: 12,
            favs: 90
         },
          category: "History",
          userid: sid._id
        });
         book.save((err, data) => {
    if (err)
      console.log(err);

    res.json(data);
    });
});
});
```

sorry for late reply. Note: I have to post my data from that url "localhost:3000/books/new" ı am using postman for testing.